# Regular expression for a name that can contain not more than one space character

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I'm struggling to find a regular expression that matches a name that can contain a space in it. So far this is what I've tried:

```
^(?![\s]+$)(?![\s]{2,})[a-zA-Z\s]{2,25}$
```

Unfortunately I'm not so good on regex. The name can contain only letters and optionally a space character, and if a space is present there must be no more than one space character in the word. The whole name length (counting also the space) must be between 2 and 25 characters long. Here some examples of names that have to match:

- Some Name
- SingleWordName

Here some examples of names that have not to match the regular expression:

- (a name full a space characters)
- Some  Name (two spaces between Some and Name)

The last requirement is that I have to use this regular expression both in javascript and php.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are more than 2 words separated by a space allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `^(?![\s]+$)(?![\s]{2,})[a-zA-Z\s]{2,25}$` that you tried matches:

- Assert that the string does not consist of 1 or more whitespace chars `^(?![\s]+$)`
- Asserts not 2 or more whitespace chars at the beginning `(?![\s]{2,})`
- Match 2-25 chars being either a-zA-Z or a whitespace char `[a-zA-Z\s]{2,25}$`

There is no restriction to match a single space   in the whole string

Note that `\s` could also match a newline or a tab.

---

What you could do is assert 2-25 characters in the string.

Then match 1+ chars a-zA-Z and optionally match a single space and 1+ chars a-zA-Z

```
^(?=.{2,25}$)[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)?$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=.{2,25}$)` Positive lookahead, assert 2-25 chars in the string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` Match 1+ chars A-Za-z
- `(?: [a-zA-Z]+)?` Optionally match   and again 1+ chars from the character class
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jWeAy2/1).

Comment: "and optionally match a single space and 1+ chars a-zA-Z" why I haven't tought about it, great solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could match the string with the following regular expression.

```
^(?!.* .* )[a-zA-Z ]{2,25}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DEIjk8/1)

The elements of the expression are as follows.

```
^                # match beginning of string
(?!.* .* )       # negative lookahead asserts the string does not
                 # contain two (or more) spaces
[a-zA-Z ]{2,25}  # match between 2 and 25 letters and spaces
$                # match end of string
```

Comment: very elegant solution, thank you! I have just learnt that is possible to negate two characters at the same time :)